# SIGSEGV Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, crash, segmentation-fault

Observing a SIGSEGV type crash in com.apple.root.default-qos.

Does anyone have an idea of what IMPings is?

Cannot find it anywhere in our codebase.

```
#25. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1fc2d1430 objc_retain + 16
1  XXX                            0x1063cc334 -[IMPingsDAO insertPing:] + 6862076
2  XXX                            0x1063d22e0 __27-[IMPingStore processPing:]_block_invoke + 6886568
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1fcb216c8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1fcb22484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1fcac5490 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 680
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1fcad1a18 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1fcad22c0 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fcd0517c _pthread_wqthread + 472
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1fcd07cec start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log so you can see the exact line of code in your `IMPingsDAO insertPing:` method that is causing the crash.

Comment: Appears to be related to Adobe AIR ?

Comment: it is related to an adnetwok called inmobi, try to contact them to kelp you resolving the problem